# Android Can’t receive data response from Firebase real-time database on specific WiFi

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

On some specific WiFi Android device can’t receive data when listener from real-time database and show log as image attached

But when change WiFi to another it work fine.
IOS device work fine with every WiFi

Please help me resolved this issue

Comment: It sounds to me like a TCP issue. Firebase uses (Fairly certain) Sockets to connect, which requires TCP connections to be active and working. If your device disables TCP connection or, more likely in your situation, your router has TCP disabled somehow, it would prevent sockets from working correctly. 
Check your router's admin panel and see if you have it disabled somehow. 
Also, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50818872/2480714 , check if you have port 443 disabled or forwarded in your router admin panel

Comment: @Silmarilos Thank you!
It work fine after I reset router!

Comment: YW, go ahead and apply the bounty to Gaston's Answer below as he indicated it was a connectivity issue originating from the modem / router.

Comment: @DaoLQ I think that it's better to forget WiFi password from your phone and scan WiFi and again and enter password and check if it receive data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the code itself, but instead in the network connection of that wifi spot.

If it wasn't working for any network provider you should care about the code, but in this case, it seems it's a connectivity issue, not a Firebase issue.

Comment: How I resolve this issues?
This wifi can access to the internet to view any page/app but not connect with Realtime Database

Comment: I think the problem is not in your code, but instead of the network, you should see whats wrong with your network, if you have any problem with your code let us know in another question

Comment: Thanks you!
But I expect solution for this issue :(

Comment: stackoverflow its about technical questions about the code you have done to solve an issue, if that code does not work or something is giving you problems, we are here to help, but in this specific case, there is no code involved in your problem, instead, it seems more a hardware and network issue than a firebase - code related issue.

Comment: But It appears in more wifi. I think this issues relative firebase

Comment: @DaoLQ I agree with Gastón Saillén, I think you need to investigate more on the lines of, 1. Does it not work for all android on a specific wifi. 2. Check the wifi channel. 3. Check network noise. etc

Comment: @SubirKumarSao This wifi can access to the internet to view any page/app but not connect with Real-time Database (Android only) :(

Comment: @DaoLQ Even I have faced this problem. That time I was using my Linux laptop to create adhoc network and my device was communicating to internet using this adhoc network, but when I switched my network to normal WiFi connection I was able to communicate with FCM.

Comment: It seems that the first step that is ok is the token fetching, that is done on the HTTP layer. Then the second step is done through websocket, so through pure TCP connections. I would then say that the HTTP connection is ok but the pure TCP connection is not ok, so you should check what are the firewall rules on the WIFI router (probably it allows HTTP connections but no TCP connections under/over a certain value).