# Firewall configuration for Firebase Authentification (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have built an Android app which uses Firebase for user authentication. Our (large enterprise) client is planning to deploy it behind their firewall. During initial testing, the authentication stage fails whenever we are using their network. It does work on an open network.

I am trying to find out what firewall configuration is needed to use the firebase authentication API, but I cannot find anything in the docs. I know that the firewall allows port 80 and 443 for outgoing connections. I am assuming that no specific IPs are blacklisted. Ports 5228-5230 (which would be required for FCM) are not opened yet, as we are currently not using push notifications. I am wondering if this is the issue. However, all references I can find (usually inofficial ones on stackoverflow) insist that the firebase authentification happens via https and only 443 should be needed.

Is anyone able to verify this and perhaps provide the documentation which details this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811695/which-ports-have-to-be-open-to-communicate-with-firebase-database-not-fcm-messa) out.

Comment: Thats exactly what I found. But I am looking for an authoritative source. Because it does not work for me even though 443 is open. But maybe it is the websockets.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, the one who answered that question, can be considered a authoritative source :) And yes, check the websockets ;)

Comment: also websockets seem to work (tried on www.websockets.org/echo.html)